# What is an easy way to understand the Intermediate value theorem?

Tags: limits, functions

> Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-4}$ , Use Intermediate value theorem to show that $f(x) = 5\sin x$ has a solution for $2<x<3$,

The never truly understand the theorem fully, so I am working on examples to see if makes sense.

so, $\sqrt{x^2-4} = 5\sin x$, $g(x) =\sqrt{x^2-4} - 5\sin x = 0$

$g(2) = \sqrt{2^2 -4} - 5\sin (2) = -4.546 (<0)$

$g(3) = \sqrt{3^2-4} - 5\sin(4) = 1.5304 (>0)$

I am just following step by step from what I learned how to solve it, but I never knew the meaning of doing it. Example,

> Why must we find $g(2), g(3)$ ? and also $g(2)= -4.546 (<0)$ what does this values and $<0$ really mean?

And from here, I need to apply the theorem to get to a conclusion which Im unclear of as I don't really understand the theorem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Intermediate Value theorem says that continuous functions take on every value between any two known values. For example, if $f(0)=10$ and $f(1)=15$, then for any value between $10$ and $15$, for example $12.7$, there must be an input between $0$ and $1$, say $c$ such that $f(c)=12.7$.

In your case, you want to show that your function $g$ equals $0$ for some value between $2$ and $3$. Since you know that $g(2)\lt 0$ and $g(3)\gt 0$, there must be some value $x$ such that $2\lt x\lt 3$ and $g(x)=0$.